# Validate Email Address on ASP.NET C# for custom ac.uk address

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, visual-studio-2010, email-validation

I know that you can use the regular expression validation on ASP.NET C# to validate an email address. However for the program I'm doing I need to register users on a system where they use their work  email addresses which end with ac.uk . Is there a way I could modify the regular expression

> **\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*.\w+([-.]\w+)***

in away that it only allows people to register who has email addresses such as example@bre.ac.uk ?

please help

Thank you

Comment: If you are saying that all your email addresses will always end in "@bre.ac.uk" then just set that as your text. I modified a previous answer here as an example. `[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@(b|B)(r|R)(e|E).(a|A)(c|C).(u|U)(|k|K)$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer to this, Thanks for the help anyway everyone]

> \w+([-+.]\w+)*@bat.ac.uk

That did the job for me

Answer (score 2):

It's bad practice to try to regex email addresses. Accept the email address as correct and try sending a confirmation email to the address to prove it exists.

Here's a sample regex off the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) website (which will explain why emails shouldn't be regex'd):

```
^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to register users who has an ac.uk email so i can send them a verification email before allowing them to register

Comment: @user1972594 are you trying to check the email address for the `ac.uk` because you can just use [string.EndsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131430.aspx) for that.

Comment: basically I'm doing a registration form where people can register, in that I will be asking for thier email address's If i could put a regex validation that captures any other emails example: xxx@gmail.com, or xxx@ yahoo.com, and only allow xxx@bat.ac.uk i could implement a system that sends an email to the registering person asking them to validate it. I know how to implement the email bit I'm just stuck at this validation part. hope this makes sense